# Contour plot data (lat,lon,value) within boundaries and export GeoJSON

Tags: python, csv, interpolation, geojson, contour

I'm trying to interpolate data within boundaries and plot contour lines (polygons) based on Latitude, longitude, value data from csv files.

Results I want print as geojson.

I'm stuck on the basic contour plot from csv. I really appreciate help here.

This is what I got in this moment but can't make it work.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = np.genfromtxt('temp.csv', delimiter=',')

x = data[:1]
y = data[:2]
[x,y] = meshgrid(x,y);
z = data[:3];

plt.contour(x,y,z)
plt.show()
```

The CSV looks like this

```
2015-10-28T09:25:12.800Z,51.56325,17.529043333,4.6484375,19.8046875
2015-10-28T09:25:12.900Z,51.56325,17.529041667,4.4921875,19.6875
2015-10-28T09:25:13.000Z,51.563248333,17.529041667,4.453125,19.9609375
2015-10-28T09:25:13.200Z,51.563245,17.529041667,4.140625,19.765625
2015-10-28T09:25:13.300Z,51.563243333,17.529041667,4.609375,19.6484375
2015-10-28T09:25:13.500Z,51.563241667,17.529041667,4.609375,19.53125
2015-10-28T09:25:13.600Z,51.56324,17.529041667,4.4921875,19.375
2015-10-28T09:25:13.700Z,51.563238333,17.529041667,4.4140625,19.765625
2015-10-28T09:25:13.800Z,51.563236667,17.529041667,4.453125,20.234375
2015-10-28T09:25:13.900Z,51.563235,17.529041667,4.3359375,19.84375
2015-10-28T09:25:14.000Z,51.563233333,17.529041667,4.53125,19.453125
2015-10-28T09:25:14.100Z,51.563231667,17.529041667,4.53125,19.8046875
2015-10-28T09:25:14.200Z,51.563228333,17.529041667,4.1796875,19.4921875
2015-10-28T09:25:14.300Z,51.563226667,17.529041667,4.2578125,19.453125
2015-10-28T09:25:14.400Z,51.563225,17.529041667,4.4921875,19.4921875
2015-10-28T09:25:14.500Z,51.563223333,17.529041667,4.375,19.453125
2015-10-28T09:25:14.600Z,51.563221667,17.529041667,4.609375,18.90625
2015-10-28T09:25:14.700Z,51.563218333,17.529041667,4.53125,19.6875
2015-10-28T09:25:14.900Z,51.563215,17.529041667,4.140625,18.75
2015-10-28T09:25:15.000Z,51.563213333,17.529041667,4.453125,18.828125
```

Column 1 - Latitude
Column 2 - Longitude
Column 3 - Value

For contour lines I need also limits - for example  (4.1,4.3,4.6)

Comment: I guess there is a few step between your code and having a geojson as output. Did you experience some error message when running your code ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess there is some mistake in your code (according to your data you shouldn't do `x = data[:1]` but more `x = data[..., 1]`).

With your of data, the basic steps I will follow to interpolate the `z` value and fetch an output as a geojson would require at least the [`shapely`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) module (and here [`geopandas`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopandas) is used for the convenience).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPolygon

def collec_to_gdf(collec_poly):
    """Transform a `matplotlib.contour.QuadContourSet` to a GeoDataFrame"""
    polygons, colors = [], []
    for i, polygon in enumerate(collec_poly.collections):
        mpoly = []
        for path in polygon.get_paths():
            try:
                path.should_simplify = False
                poly = path.to_polygons()
                # Each polygon should contain an exterior ring + maybe hole(s):
                exterior, holes = [], []
                if len(poly) > 0 and len(poly[0]) > 3:
                    # The first of the list is the exterior ring :
                    exterior = poly[0]
                    # Other(s) are hole(s):
                    if len(poly) > 1:
                        holes = [h for h in poly[1:] if len(h) > 3]
                mpoly.append(Polygon(exterior, holes))
            except:
                print('Warning: Geometry error when making polygon #{}'
                      .format(i))
        if len(mpoly) > 1:
            mpoly = MultiPolygon(mpoly)
            polygons.append(mpoly)
            colors.append(polygon.get_facecolor().tolist()[0])
        elif len(mpoly) == 1:
            polygons.append(mpoly[0])
            colors.append(polygon.get_facecolor().tolist()[0])
    return GeoDataFrame(
        geometry=polygons,
        data={'RGBA': colors},
        crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'})


data = np.genfromtxt('temp.csv', delimiter=',')
x = data[..., 1]
y = data[..., 2]
z = data[..., 3]
xi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 200)
yi = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 200)
zi = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='linear') # You could also take a look to scipy.interpolate.griddata

nb_class = 15 # Set the number of class for contour creation
# The class can also be defined by their limits like [0, 122, 333]
collec_poly = plt.contourf(
    xi, yi, zi, nb_class, vmax=abs(zi).max(), vmin=-abs(zi).max())

gdf = collec_to_gdf(collec_poly)
gdf.to_json()
# Output your collection of features as a GeoJSON:
# '{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[51.563214073747474,
# (...)
```

Edit:
You can grab the colors values (as an array of 4 values in range 0-1, representing RGBA values) used by matplotplib by fetching them on each item of the collection with the `get_facecolor()` method (and then use them to populate one (or 4) column of your GeoDataFrame :

```
colors = [p.get_facecolor().tolist()[0] for p in collec_poly.collections]
gdf['RGBA'] = colors
```

Once you have you GeoDataFrame you can easily get it intersected with your boundaries. Use these boundaries to make a Polygon with shapely and compute the intersection with your result:

```
mask = Polygon([(51,17), (51,18), (52,18), (52,17), (51,17)])
gdf.geometry = gdf.geometry.intersection(mask)
```

Or read your geojson as a GeoDataFrame:

```
from shapely.ops import unary_union, polygonize
boundary = GeoDataFrame.from_file('your_geojson')
# Assuming you have a boundary as linestring, transform it to a Polygon:
mask_geom = unary_union([i for i in polygonize(boundary.geometry)])
# Then compute the intersection:
gdf.geometry = gdf.geometry.intersection(mask_geom)
```

Comment: Thank you, this will help me a lot. I was try to plot the results first but I have an error if I use all of my data about 40k points. Error in griddata (RuntimeError: In initialize: Triangulation is invalid).  Maybe I need to sort this data first ? But how?

Comment: I have boundaries as a Polygon (sometimes even polygon with holes) in geojson file.

geometry.intersection gives me very strange results. Showing only smallest polygons inside. 

About RGBA colors I have error: "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index" at gdf['RGBA'] = colors

Comment: I'm sorry. I doesn't use this unary_union function on my boundaries polygon. Now its looks like it works.. If you can check why this colors doesnt work for me will be great.

Comment: If your boundaries file has multiple features you should try `mask_geom = unary_union(your_boundary_gdf.geometry)` before `gdf.geometry.intersection(mask_geom)`. About the colors i guess it is because some polygons from the matplotlib collection where not fetched as shapely geometry (invalid ones) so it could explain the mismatch of the length. A safer way would have been to fetch them in the `collec_to_gdf` function for each polygon created.

Comment: @user3476099 i edited the `collec_to_gdf` function so it should outputs a `GeoDataFrame` with a column for RGBA values.

Comment: Great. Thank you. But I have the same error as earlier ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: You're welcome, i hoped this would work.. So..look at the new edit in this function code, i moved the `colors.append(...)` part, it has more chance now to fit the length of the polygons created. (you also can try to `print(len(colors))` and `print(len(polygons))` to see i there is a big difference (and try to guess from where it comes!))

Comment: Works like a charm. Once again thank you! I changed RGBA attribute into two - fill & fill-opacity to fit into geojson guidelines.

Comment: I figure it out that if my masking polygon have hole inside this geometry.intersection doesn't use this hole. Do you know how to handle this?

Comment: How would one do this without `geopandas`, using shapely and pandas ++?

Comment: @M.T You can totally do the same without geopandas (as it is almost not involved in this code, just as a contained for the result). At the end of the function `collec_to_gdf` you just have to replace `return GeoDataFrame(...` by something like `return polygons` if you want a list (it's a python `list` filled by the shapely polygons previously computed) or by something like `return pd.DataFrame({"my_geoms": polygons})` if you want a pandas DataFrame, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Almost I got what I excepted. Based on mgc answer. I change griddata as you suggest to scipy.interpolate.griddata and interpolation method to nearest. Now its works like I want.

Only last thing that I need is to limit this interpolation to polygon (boundaries) also from geoJson.

The other problem is to export to geojson polygons WITH colors as attributes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPolygon

def collec_to_gdf(collec_poly):
    """Transform a `matplotlib.contour.QuadContourSet` to a GeoDataFrame"""
    polygons = []
    for i, polygon in enumerate(collec_poly.collections):
        mpoly = []
        for path in polygon.get_paths():
            try:
                path.should_simplify = False
                poly = path.to_polygons()
                # Each polygon should contain an exterior ring + maybe hole(s):
                exterior, holes = [], []
                if len(poly) > 0 and len(poly[0]) > 3:
                    # The first of the list is the exterior ring :
                    exterior = poly[0]
                    # Other(s) are hole(s):
                    if len(poly) > 1:
                        holes = [h for h in poly[1:] if len(h) > 3]
                mpoly.append(Polygon(exterior, holes))
            except:
                print('Warning: Geometry error when making polygon #{}'
                      .format(i))
        if len(mpoly) > 1:
            mpoly = MultiPolygon(mpoly)
            polygons.append(mpoly)
        elif len(mpoly) == 1:
            polygons.append(mpoly[0])
    return GeoDataFrame(geometry=polygons, crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'})

data = np.genfromtxt('temp2.csv', delimiter=',')
x = data[..., 1]
y = data[..., 2]
z = data[..., 4]
xi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), num=100)
yi = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), num=100)

#zi = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='nn') # You could also take a look to scipy.interpolate.griddata
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='nearest')

nb_class = [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50] # Set the number of class for contour creation
# The class can also be defined by their limits like [0, 122, 333]
collec_poly = plt.contourf(
    xi, yi, zi, nb_class, vmax=abs(zi).max(), vmin=-abs(zi).max())

gdf = collec_to_gdf(collec_poly)
#gdf.to_json()
print gdf.to_json()

plt.plot(x,y)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I edited my answer about the colors and the boundaries.